# Char stores entire strings with Scanf?

Tags: c, char, scanf

So i'm taking lessons on C at my university and the professor showed this simple bit of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char c;
    scanf("%c", &c);
    while (c !='.'){
        //if(c != '/n');
        scanf("%c", &c);
        printf("%c", c);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And although for many of you it's an objectively simple piece of code, i can't wrap my head around two things. The first thing is if you run the code, i can store entire strings (by writing in the `scanf()`) and have the code spit it back to me. But the variable i'm storing it in is a type `char`, which only goes up to 127, which based on the ASCII values of the characters i'm typing, isn't nearly enough so how does it store it? 
Secondhing is that i'm writing this code from memory (although i think its the exact same one as the one my prof. used). However, in his code the program stops after it detects a full stop ".", and the program prints its final string without printing the dot, but mine does. I wonder if wrote it incorrectly or if theres something wrong with my compiler (Clion, lang on a mac)? 
I know that the second one isn't really related with the title but i appreciate the answers, so thanks!

Comment: I recommend you change the `printf` line to `printf("%d\n", c);` so you can see tha actual value and not be misled by whitespace.

Comment: The code doesn't read or print strings. It reads and prints single characters.

Comment: Also, almost all systems in use today uses [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) encoding for characters, and ASCII is a 7-bit encoding (with values from `0` to `127`). So it fits well in a (signed) `char`.

Comment: If your program does not behave quite like the professor's, then it isn't the same. Note that in the loop, you output the character temporally *before* the next loop's `while` test finds the `'.'`. Notice too that you never output the result of the first `scanf` which is outside the loop. I suggest you move the `printf` up one line.

Comment: how would i change it so that the code ends and doesn't print out the '.' at the end?

Comment: I mentioned that in the previous comment.

Comment: Oh dear.  It is 2019 and university instructors are still using scanf in the introductory course?  Why?!

Comment: I don't get it, why wouldn't/shouldn't they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In your while loop it is not storing entered character as string.
   It'll keep replacing(overwriting) the old value with the new value and will print that new value in c right after storing it. A character type variable can hold just 1 character at a time.
   In simple words the value you will enter from keyboard will be stored in variable c "By Replacing" the old value..
   So at any time c will have only 1 character stored in it that's the latest character read using scanf.

127 that you mentioned.. Everywhere you'll find that char ranges from -127 to 128 right. That does not mean you can store 127 characters in its variable,but that means that you can store 256 types of characters in its variable. Learn more about ASCII value. Every character got an ASCII value associated with it because characters are internally represented as integers.

Read more about ASCII value
You can refer to these articles

https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html

https://www.atnyla.com/tutorial/char-data-type-in-c/1/178

2.
Regarding full stop
In your loop condition you have

```
while( c !=  '.' ){
    scanf("%c", &c);
    printf("%c", c);
}
```

Your program prints the full stop
Because see from while

1. It will check if ch is equal to '.' it is not full stop it'll go inside
   eg., Suppose I entered: a as a first character then . as a second character
   Intially before while loop you have entered some character already. So if you enter first character as full stop your loop won't execute..
   But if not
   Suppose you entered : abc.
   The scanf before loop body will execute and take 'a'
   It is not full stop it will print 'a'
   Right now c has 'a'
   Then it will check a=='.' which is false
   Loop will execute and take input 'b'
   It will print 'b' then check if it is full stop 
   It's not
   Loop will again execute and take input.. You entered 'c'
   It will print 'c' then check if it is full stop

FOCUS
Right now c variable has value of 'c'. It's not '.'
Loop condition 'c' is not equal to '.' loop will execute
It will take Input using scanf
Now you entered '.' i.e., c is '.' now`enter code here`
It will go to next line
And print c i.e., '.' 
Then will check again now c is equal to '.'
Hence loop will terminate

I hope that explains why are you getting . in output

Answer (score 1):

You're right, a variable of type `char` can hold one character.  In no way can it hold a string of multiple characters.

But this program does not have to hold a string of multiple characters.  It reads a character and prints it, and reads a character and prints it, etc.

*If* you were using `scanf %s` to read and store a whole string, and `printf %s` to print that string, then yes, you would need an array of multiple characters.

Based on the way your loop is written, I would expect it to print the `'.'`, then stop.  Follow it carefully: inside the loop, it reads a character, and prints the character, then it goes "back to the top" off the loop to decide if it should make another trip through thw loop.  (That's the way `while` loops work.)  After reading and printing the `'.'`, the condition `while(c != '.')` is no longer true, so the loop stops -- but by then the `'.'` has been printed.  There's nothing wrong with your compiler.

You mentioned `char` going up to 127.  Actually, an 8-bit `char` can hold 2<sup>8</sup> = 256 different values.  We can think of those values as running from -128 to +127 (if `char` is a signed type) or 0 to 255 (if `char` is an unsigned type).  The ordinary ASCII characters always have values less than 128, so there's never any problem representing those.  The other 128 values can be used in different ways depending on your machine's character set and encoding.